# JSON Parsing Error (blank response)

Tags: objective-c, json

Here's my code, when I run it, I get: "2014-10-26 19:02:09.153 App[27372:1281902] Price: (
)".

I was wondering why, no errors are being passed through and it honestly confuses me.

(I'm getting a blank response for "omc_usd_price")

```
@try
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://omnicha.in/api?method=getinfo"];
    NSData *data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    NSError *error;

    NSMutableDictionary *JSONStuff= [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &error];

    NSLog(@"%@",JSONStuff);

    NSMutableArray * OMCArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    NSArray * responseArr = JSONStuff[@"omc_usd_price"];

    for(NSDictionary * dict in responseArr)
    {
        [OMCArray addObject:[dict valueForKey:@"omc_usd_price"]];

    }


    NSLog(@"Price: %@ test", OMCArray);   // Here you get the Referance data
}
@catch (NSException *exception) {
    NSLog(@"%@", exception);

}
@finally {

}
```

EDIT:

Tried this, I don't think I did this right either!

```
NSMutableArray * OMCArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSMutableArray * OMCArray2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    NSArray * responseArr = JSONStuff[@"response"];
    NSArray * responseArr2 = JSONStuff[@"omc_usd_price"];

    for(NSDictionary * dict in responseArr)
    {
        [OMCArray addObject:[dict valueForKey:@"response"]];

        for(NSDictionary * dict2 in responseArr2)
        {
            [OMCArray addObject:[dict2 valueForKey:@"omc_usd_price"]];
        }
    }


    NSLog(@"Price: %@ test", OMCArray2);   // Here you get the Referance data
```

Comment: Well if `JSONStuff[@"omc_usd_price"]` comes up empty or nil you could get that.  And since there is no entry in the dictionary JSONStuff named "omc_usd_price" that would be expected.

Comment: You're right -- that's not right.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the JSONStuff dictionary:

```
{
    "error":false,
    "response":{
        "block_count":96136,
        "difficulty":12.18364177,
        "netmhps":234.652099,
        "seconds_since_block":694,
        "avg_block_time":196.533,
        "total_mined_omc":6426691.6,
        "omc_btc_price":7.0e-6,
        "omc_usd_price":0.0025,
        "market_cap":15833.5909
    }
}
```

As you can see, there is no entry in the dictionary named "omc_usd_price".  There *is* a entry by that name in the dictionary name "response", but you didn't ask for that.

Comment: Could you please go into detail on how I could fix this? Sorry, I'm not that good at ObjC.

Comment: You have a dictionary inside a dictionary.  Get the inner dictionary, then ask for you price entry in it.

Comment: I tried something else (what I thought you guys meant) - Didn't work either.

Comment: Hint:  Use NSLog to display the values of `JSONStuff[@"error"]` and `JSONStuff[@"response"]`.

Comment: I got a blank space displaying 'error' and 'responce' using this code:  NSLog(@"%@", JSONStuff[@"response"]);

Comment: Then try displaying JSONStuff itself the same way.

Comment: NSLog(@"%@",JSONStuff);

This works, but it displays everything.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get omc_usd_price, as mentioned on your code, then you need to parse 2 dictionaries.
You must first parse the dictionary with the key response, and this will give you a new dictionary.

Then in this new dictionary you must parse/look for the key omc_usd_price.

Also, you're not getting an array back, but a double or float or even a string.